# WebSocket on server doesn't seem to send messages to frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, fastify

Here is a setup using NodeJs/Fastify on the backend.
It's all in local environment:

Server side:

```
////// Instantiate app
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true });
const path = require('path');
fastify.register(require('@fastify/static'), {
  root: path.join(__dirname, 'public-static'),
})
fastify.register(require('@fastify/websocket'));

/////// Template engine
fastify.register(require("@fastify/view"), {
  engine: {
    ejs: require("ejs"),
  },
});


/////// Routes Controllers
fastify.register(async function (fastify) {
    fastify.get('/ws', { websocket: true }, (connection /* SocketStream */, req /* FastifyRequest */) => {
  connection.socket.on('message', message => {

    connection.socket.send('hi from server');

    let interval = setInterval(function() {
      connection.socket.send('hi from server');
      console.log('This will run every 0.5 second');
    }, 500);

  })
 })
})

/////// Run the server!
const start = async () => {
  try {
    await fastify.listen({ port: 3000 })
  } catch (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}
start()
```

I expect this to send every 500ms a "hi from server" data to the frontend:

```
<%- include('header'); -%>

<script>
console.log("browser"); // Works fine


let socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:3000/ws");

// Connection opened
socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    console.log('WebSocket is open now.');
});

// Listen for messages
socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log('Message from server: ', event.data);
});

</script>

<%- include('footer'); -%>
```

I can see in browser console the log: "WebSocket is open now." so the connection is correctly open. But it doesn't receive any data. I expected it would receive repetadly the 'hi from server'.

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send messages after receive message from client.

```
connection.socket.on('message', message => { ... })
```

Move your code outside message handler.
Checked on my end, it's working as expected.

```
fastify.register(async function(fastify) {
  fastify.get('/chat', {websocket: true}, (connection, req) => {
    connection.socket.send('hi from server');

    let interval = setInterval(function() {
      connection.socket.send('hi from server');
      console.log('This will run every 0.5 second');
    }, 500);
  })
})
```